# Modify jQuery ajax settings from callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax call to a url. On success I need to modify this url for subsequent calls. How can I access the settings to do so?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //set url here to http://yahoo.com
    }
```

Comment: Updated my code. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

function getUrl()
{
  count++;
  if ( count == 1 )
    return 'http://google.com';
  else
    return 'http://yahoo.com';
}

$.ajax({
    url: getUrl(),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    }
});
```

Comment: That might work but not in my case - I need to update the url with data from my callback - yahoo/google are just examples

Comment: well basically you can't do it since you don't know when exactly the success callback executes(it's async)

Answer (score 0):

```
var customUrl = 'http://google.com'

$.ajax({
    url: customUrl ,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //set url here to http://yahoo.com

        customUrl = 'http://yahoo.com'

        use your customUrl variable later
    }
});
```

Ajax is asynchronous. So if you want to use the url at a later time , it is better to use it in success callback function...

If you are using it immediately after the ajax request there might be a possibility that the ajax request is still not completed and the variable was not updated when you try to access it

Comment: I need to modify the customUrl that the ajax function uses so that the next time I submit it it uses the new URL. This doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - figured it out. My issue was that my call was wrapped in a form on submit and that updating the url within this call does not work. However moving the url outside of the call allows me to update it from the callback.

This does not work:

```
$("#form").bind("submit", function(evt) {   
  var url = "http://myurl";
  $.ajax({
    url:  url,
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      url = "http://newurl" 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
  });
  return false;
});
```

But this does:

```
var url = "http://myurl";
$("#form").bind("submit", function(evt) {
  $.ajax({
    url:  url,
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      url = "http://newurl" 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
  });
  return false;
});
```